# Sessions in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: session, cakephp

I just upgraded my app from CakePHP 1.3 to 2.3. The upgrade console is far from perfect, but after a day of debugging, I've solved most of the issues. There's just one left, and it's a big one: **Sessions**.

In my app I am not using any  of the fancy $this->Session or CakeSession::read login, I've always relied on **PHP Superglobal $_SESSION**. In 1.3, that worked fine.

Enter CakePHP 2.3: Sessions seem to work only at some places in my functions, and for unknown reasons, they are sometimes empty. One example: in line 1 of a function in a controller, $_SESSION['key'] gives me an empty array, in line 10 it will give me a nicely populated array, and in my view it's empty again. Extremely frustrating. I've been able to solve this by calling session_start() when it doesn't work, but I don't want to go down that road.

The documentation states:

> Usage of the $_SESSION is generally avoided in CakePHP, and instead usage of the Session classes is preferred.

I'm a bit surprised: Cake runs on PHP, so I would expect PHP superglobals to work.

I'm considering switching to CakeSession::read and CakeSession::write, but that's a laborious task: I'm using Sessions throughout my app.

Before switching, I'd like to know:

- Is there a way to make the normal PHP $_SESSION superglobal work in Cakephp 2.3.7?
- If not: is CakeSession::read and CakeSession::write the right alternative?

Some extra info:

- I am calling the Session component in my AppController
- I am calling the Session helper in my AppController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could access $_SESSION itself, but then you would need to assert session start and other things manually, as well - which CakePHP can and should take care of itself.
So why bother when you got a nice wrapper access to it?

I dont really see why this needs to be a question here. There are usually bigger fish to fry.
Believe me when I say that everyone uses the clean and neat component/helper/CakeSession access.

Also a nice site effect: You cannot trigger any "undefined index" warnings with the wrapper methods. They would simply return null if this key has not been set yet.

```
I am calling the Session component in my AppController
I am calling the Session helper in my AppController
```

No, helpers are for the view layer.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I wouldn't is because it's a helluva job. But if it's best practice, I'll do it:)